# Accessing Sonic MQ registered JNDI objects behind a firewall

Tags: sonicmq

I'm trying to connect to Sonic MQ hosted behind a firewall from  IBM Web Sphere Message broker message flow . WMB is old v6.01. and it does not have an option to set proxy details.

I'm getting 
' There is a configuration problem with the JNDI Administered objects where:  Initial Context Factory  = 'com.sonicsw.jndi.mfcontext.MFContextFactory'.  Location of the bindings = '100.XX.X.XX:2508'.  ConnectionFactory Name   = 'QCF'.  JMS destination  = 'XXXXXXXX'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the right configuration for your JNDI store.

If it is using the Sonic JNDI store you need to have the domain connection.

Domain Name
Url
login

Both the Jndi store port and broker(s) port must be open on the firewall.

Also the url is usually: **tcp://100.XX.X.XX:2508**

BR